# Vue SPA retrieve status code on error codes (not 200) in nested promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

In my VUE components, I use this async method to fetch data from API:

**Components**:

```js
methods: {
  async fetch() {
    // console.log("##### WAIT ####");
    const { data } = await staffRepository.getItems(this.teamId)
    // console.log("##### END WAIT ####");
    this.staffs = data
  },
},
```

As you can see I use a custom repository to have a single axios code, this repository is imported in my previous component.

**staffRepository**:

```js
export default {
  getItems(nationId) {
    return Repository.get(`page/${nationId}`)
  },
}
```

And finally the main repository having the axios code:

**Repository**:

```js
import axios from 'axios/index'
const baseDomain = 'https://my end point'
const baseURL = `${baseDomain}`
...
const headers = {
  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token,
  //  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // IF you ADD it add 'allowedHeaders' to ai server config/cors.php
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtoken}`,
}
export default axios.create({
  baseURL,
  withCredentials: withCredentials,
  headers: headers,
})
```

This code works very nice when the jwtoken is a valid and NOT EXIPRED token.

The problem is when the token is expired or not found and my laravel 5.8 API returns the status code 401 (or other).

> GET https://api.endpoint 401 (Unauthorized)

A good solution could catch the status code in **staffRepository**, the one having the get method.

**MySolution**: (not working)

```js
getItems(nationId) {
  return Repository.get(`page/${nationId}`)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response.status) // <-- it works!
    })
},
```

This could be nice because in error case the error in console is **401**

But I can't use this solution because I have 2 nested promises: this one and the async fetch() into the component.

How can I fix it still using my repository environment?

Comment: What about try catch? in your fetch method?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the returned promise in your component, to make things more explicit:

```js
methods: {
  fetch() {
    let data = null

    staffRepository
      .getItems(this.teamId)
      .then(data => {
        // do something with data
        this.staffs = data
      })
      .catch(e => {
        // do something with error, or tell the user
      })
  },
},
```

Edit - this will work perfectly fine, as your method in Repository will return a promise by default if you are using axios.

Try this: API code, where HTTP is an axios instance

```js
export const get = (path: string): Promise<any> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    HTTP.get(`${path}`)
      .then((response) => {
        resolve(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(handleError(error));
      });
  });
};

// ***** Handle errors *****/

export function handleError(error) {
  if (error.response) {
    const status = error.response.status;

    switch (status) {
      case 400:
        // do something
        break;
      case 401:
        // do something, maybe log user out
        break;
      case 403:
        break;
      case 500:
        // server error...
        break;
      default:
      // handle normal errors here
    }
  }
  return error; // Return the error message, or whatever you want to your components/vue files
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ralph, I did it in my previous test but I'm not able to catch the status error. If I do a console.log(e) in catch(e) I got an object having a string as : Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (app.js:58343)
    at settle (app.js:58589)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:57856). How catch the status code without searching text in string?

Comment: at that point `e.response.status` should be available. However, in your component you shouldn't really be thinking about the status code, I would handle that at API level. Check my edit for a half decent pattern for that

Comment: Thanks very  helpful. I'm going to update my code to Handle errors in my repository code, the one having the axios.create({..}) but not sure how to do.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice solution is to use `axios`'s interceptors:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

export default (options = {}) => {
  let client = options.client || axios.create({ baseURL: process.env.baseUrl });
  let token = options.token || Cookies.get("token");
  let refreshToken = options.refreshToken || Cookies.get("refreshToken");
  let refreshRequest = null;

  client.interceptors.request.use(
    config => {
      if (!token) {
        return config;
      }

      const newConfig = {
        headers: {},
        ...config
      };

      newConfig.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
      return newConfig;
    },
    e => Promise.reject(e)
  );

  client.interceptors.response.use(
    r => r,
    async error => {
      if (
        !refreshToken ||
        error.response.status !== 401 ||
        error.config.retry
      ) {
        throw error;
      }

      if (!refreshRequest) {
        refreshRequest = client.post("/auth/refresh", {
          refreshToken
        });
      }

      const { data } = await refreshRequest;
      const { token: _token, refreshToken: _refreshToken } = data.content;

      token = _token;
      Cookies.set("token", token);

      refreshRequest = _refreshToken;
      Cookies.set("refreshToken", _refreshToken);

      const newRequest = {
        ...error.config,
        retry: true
      };

      return client(newRequest);
    }
  );

  return client;
};
```

Take a look at `client.interceptors.response.use`. Also you should have a `refreshToken`. We are intercepting `401` response and sending post request to refresh our token, then waiting for a new *fresh* token and resending our previous request. It's very elegant and tested solution that fits my company needs, and probably will fit your needs too.

To send request use:

```
import api from './api'

async function me() {
  try {
    const res = await api().get('/auth/me')
    // api().post('/auth/login', body) <--- POST

    if (res.status === 200) { alert('success') }
  } catch(e) {
    // do whatever you want with the error
  }
}
```

> Refresh token: The refresh token is used to generate a new access
>   token. Typically, if the access token has an expiration date, once it
>   expires, the user would have to authenticate again to obtain an access
>   token. With refresh token, this step can be skipped and with a request
>   to the API get a new access token that allows the user to continue
>   accessing the application resources.

Comment: thanks, very helpful too! Thanks! This is similar but different as mine. I need to check it before update mine code. Can you post also a sample request example? Just lime my own staffRepository code block.   Thanks.

Comment: I've not yet implemented the refreshToken because I need to understand the best practice about that. I thought to overwrite the token using the refreshed token but you keep it both, why?

Comment: When you are being logged in you get `token` and `refreshToken`. When your `token` expires, you get a fresh one by sending a `refreshToken`, also getting a new `refreshToken` to get  a new token when received token expires. Such a loop. Configure your token expiration date on the server.

Comment: @Uncoke, Also notice that you can store your token in different place – `localStorage`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look tomorrow. I use to store token in localStorage instead of cookie but I'm not sure about the best solution. I think also to use the refresh token in a different way ( This is the reason it is missing in my code at moment) Basically the user can see  his private data if he has a valid (or expired) token but it can delete/update/add data ONLY with a valid a not expired token.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198463/discussion-between-uncoke-and-javas).